# Integral extensions and regular local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

Let $R$ = $K[X,Y]$, where $K = \overline{K}$, and char $K = 0$. Let $\mathfrak {m} = (X,Y)$. Let $A = R^H$, where $H$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $R$, and $\sigma (\mathfrak{m}) \subset \mathfrak {m} \, \forall \, \sigma \in H$. Let $\mathfrak{n} = A \cap \mathfrak {m}$.

Thus $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a regular local ring of dimension $2$, $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ dominates $A_{\mathfrak{n}}$ and from problem 12 of Chapter 5 of Atiyah-MacDonald, we have $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is integral over $A_{\mathfrak{n}}$.

> My question is: can we show that $A_{\mathfrak{n}}$ is a regular local ring of dimension $2$ ?

Comment: No. Try an order 2 group acting via $x\mapsto -x, y\mapsto -y$.

Comment: Let me add some details to Mohan's good comment. In his example we have $A=K[X^2,XY,Y^2]$. Then $A\simeq K[X_1,X_2,X_3]/(X_1X_3-X_2^2)$ and now it's easy to see that $A_{\mathfrak n}$ is not regular.

Comment: If your group is cyclic of order $n$ and acts via $X \mapsto \zeta_n X$, $Y \mapsto \zeta_n^a Y$, you get something called cyclic quotient singularities. The action is said to be of type $\frac{1}{n}(1,a)$ and the quotient is regular if and only if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$. The example by Mohan would be a quotient of type $\frac{1}{2}(1,1)$, and therefore singular. There is a basic introduction to cyclic quotient singularities by Miles Reid.